# Slider with labels WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, slider, winrt-xaml

I am creating a WinRT/Windows 8 app that needs a slider with both bottom and top tickbars and a number label below each tick as well indicating the value of each tick.

[image: Something like this]

So far I have got the slider with the colors and the tickbars working but I cannot get the labels below the tickbars working.

I know that there was some way to do this in WPF  by creating a default class and inheriting it and overriding OnRender but I don't think that will work in WinRT since there is no DrawableContext class.

If anyone has done something like this, please help!

PS: The labels just need to have a single value and not a range value as shown in the image and so does the thumb.

Thanks

Comment: you have to make a usercontrol for it..also for removing range values you have use switch case - for implementing what range is for what number..

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the UI you want, you'll have to re-template the Slider and TickBar within it do get the values to show.

Comment: Thanks for that Tim,

Can you please provide such an example. I tried re-templating the slider using Blend and was trying to add a control inside the slider template below the lower tickbar but I do not know what value to bind the control text to.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it's done in WPF:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8d64b2dc-4dfd-4b05-aa95-e24aaaed53af/i-want-to-add-lables-with-text-in-ticks-of-slider

Correct, there's no OnRender() in WinRT XAML.  As Tim points out, you can retemplate Slider and make your own custom TickBar.  It can override ArrangeOverride() and create custom tick marks using [Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.line.aspx) or [Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.rectangle.aspx) with labels created using TextBlock.  If you don't need a generic solution, you could just overlay the Slider with TextBlocks for the labels.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I can add textblocks below the slider for the labels but a slider that has a range of 0-100 with ticks at frequency of 5 will require around 20 textblocks all of which will most probably have to be created dynamically. I was hoping for a more elegant solution!